# Unable to close emacs sessions in Windows (after Hibernate or Sleep)

Tags: microsoft-windows

When an Emacs session is created and closed before either Hibernate or Sleep options are used in Windows-7, Emacs exits normally.

But whenever either Hibernate or Sleep options are used with an Emacs session is open and after coming back from hibernate or sleep, <s>there is no clean exit</s> **the Emacs window does not close**. I see the following message when I close Emacs using `C-x C-c`

[image: exit_message]

I have enabled `ido` mode. I'm wondering if that could be a cause for this strange behavior.

If I click on the close button or press `C-x C-c` there is not effect. Finally, I'm forced to kill Emacs from Windows Task Manager using `End Task`.

Is there way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please clarify what about this message is not a clean exit?

Comment: @Dan, I have updated the question with right wording. The message I see when I press `C-x C-c` is what I have posted as screenshot and not that Emacs application does not close after the `C-x C-c` command or by pressing the `X` button.